Evaluation of $\int{\frac{1}{1-sin^4θ}dθ}$
Evaluate $$I= \int{\frac{1}{1-sin^4θ}dθ}$$
$I= {\frac12}{\left[\int{\frac{1}{1+sin^2θ}}dθ+\int{\frac{1}{1-sin^2θ}}dθ\right]}$
$= {\frac12}{\left(\int{\frac{sec^2{θ}}{1+2tan^2θ}}dθ\right)}+{\frac14}{\left[\int{\frac{1}{1-sinθ}}dθ+\int{\frac{1}{1+sinθ}}dθ\right]}$
$={\frac12}{\left(\int{\frac{sec^2{θ}}{1+2tan^2θ}}dθ\right)}+{\frac14}{\left[\int{\frac{1+tan^2{\fracθ2}}{{\left(1-tan{\fracθ2}\right)}^2}}dθ+\int{\frac{1+tan^2{\fracθ2}}{{\left(1+tan{\fracθ2}\right)}^2}}dθ\right]}$
Now, Put $tanθ=t$, $tan{\fracθ2}=y$
And so, $sec^2θdθ=dt$, ${\frac12}sec^2({\fracθ2})dθ=dy$
$I = {\frac12}{\left(\int{\frac{1}{1+2t^2}}dt\right)}+{\frac12}{\left[\int{\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}}dy+\int{\frac{1}{(1+y)^2}}dy\right]}$
$\therefore I= {\frac{1}{2√2}}tan^{-1}(√2\ t)-{\frac12}{\left({\frac{1}{1-y}}+{\frac{1}{1+y}}\right)} +c$
$Or$
$= {\frac{1}{2√2}}tan^{-1}(√2\ t)-{\frac12}{\left({\frac{1}{y-1}}+{\frac{1}{1+y}}\right)} +c$
$(1) I= {\frac{1}{2√2}}tan^{-1}(√2\ tan θ )-{\frac{1}{1-tan^2{\fracθ2}}} +c$
$Or $
$(2) I= {\frac{1}{2√2}}tan^{-1}(√2\ tan θ )+{\frac{1}{2}}{tan{θ}} +c$

In my book only (2) is given as answer, does that mean (1) is incorrect, how can in know if one should write $(1-y)$ or $(1+y)$.


If you start with $\theta=\tan^{-1}(y)$, the result is almost immediate

Yes. The first answer is incorrect. Just compare the second term:$$\frac{1}{2}\tan \theta=\frac{\tan \frac{\theta}{2}}{1-\tan\ ^2\frac{\theta}{2}}\neq-\frac{1}{1-\tan\ ^2 \frac{\theta}{2}}$$
$\int_{}\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}dy=\int_{}\frac{1}{(y-1)^2}d(y-1)=\frac{-1}{y-1}+C$. In your first method, you get $\int_{} \frac{1}{(1-y)^2}dy=\frac{1}{y-1}+C,$ which is not the case if you check the derivative of $\frac{1}{y-1}.$
